# Looping does not work for me using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have table data as follow with data attributes with different values in each row. I want to collect these values using jQuery. I had write the logic in jQuery but looping does not work for me.

```
  <table id="tblAdAttribute">

  <thead>

    <tr> </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
         foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                   <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</td>
                   <td>
                       <a href="#"><input type="checkbox" 
                   name="chkSelected" 
                   data-values="'@item.Title', @((int)item.DataType))"></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
               }
       }
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

here is my looping logic to extract the "data-values"  from HTML.

```
    var getSelectedAttributes = function () {

    var values = new Array();
    var singlevalue;
    debugger;
    $.each($("input[name='chkSelected']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td"),
           function () {
               singlevalue = $(("input[name='chkSelected']:checked")).attr("data-values");
               values.push(singlevalue);
               alert(singlevalue);  // Here i always get same value :(
           });

    SelectedAttributes =  values.join(", ");
};
```

When I do alert, it always gives first row value and not looping the rest.

Comment: Just curious: Why are you using checkbox inside anchor?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SLbxm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just using :

```
$("input[name='chkSelected']:checked").each(function () {
    singlevalue = $(this).data("values");
    values.push(singlevalue);
    alert(singlevalue);
}).promise().done(function(){
    SelectedAttributes =  values.join(", ");
});
```

Comment: can u explain technically the use of promise(), seems like initially it returns empty 'values' and then once loop over it fills the 'values'? guide me

Comment: promise() used with done() methods permits to have a callback called only when ALL previous callbacks (asynchronous by definition) (each() in this case) have been executed. It is a deffered method, we could also use when().

Answer (score 1):

You always get the same value because you are selecting the same thing in each iteration of the loop. You don't need to use `closest` or `siblings` to traverse the DOM because the `data` attribute you want is directly on the checkbox itself. Try this:

```
var getSelectedAttributes = function() {
    var values = $("input[name='chkSelected']:checked").map(function() {
        return $(this).data('values');
    }).get();
    alert(values);

    // do something with the values array here...
}
```

Here I'm using `map()` to create an array of the data attributes.

Comment: still getting same values :(  but in FireBug I can see proper values added in checkbox data attribute. i doubt its issue with html code.